# @font-face path on server

Tags: css, path, font-face

I'm sorry but I haven't found the solution reading the other questions.

That's the problem:
I'm using `@font-face` building my website and when I run the html and css files on the browser (I use firefox) from the folder that is inside my own computer, it works well.
When I load the files on the server (using a relative path, of course) and I run, it doesn't work.

here's my code:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Lupus';
src: url('font/Rom_fatl_Srif.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

I really don't understand where's the problem.
Thanks in advance and Sorry for my language (I'm Italian ;-) )

Comment: Try to use web font kit generator for your font and upload them.

Comment: try to use absolute path and see if it works. 
Check the font file name as the server could have difference between lower case and uppercase.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advices.
for Leo: I don't know what is "font kit generator" have you a link please?
for FrontMonkey: I've tried with absolute and checked the case (I've done copy and paste to be totally sure), but it doesn't work.